# Calculate Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have the following two circles (n1, n2). I know the coordinates of them. They are connected with a line. I also know the angle "alpha" and the diameter of the circles. Now I try to calculate the coordinates where the red questionmark is. The point where the line crosses the second circle.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw a horizontal line to the left from the center of n2.

Then treat it like a unit circle and draw a line straight up from the question mark.  Then the coordinates would be 
$$(x_{n2}-cos(\alpha)\times \frac{d}{2},y_{n2}-sin(\alpha)\times \frac{d}{2})$$

Due to alternate interior angles between parallel lines being congruent.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be the new coordinates wihtout esteem the diameter..?

Comment: Ha.  Yeah.  I forgot to add in the radius times the sin or cos value.  I edited my answer.  Does that look better?

Comment: thanks, is it right to get the angle $\alpha$ with $atan2(x_{n1} - x_{n2}, y_{n2}-y_{n1})$

Comment: Oh, sorry.  $\alpha$ is the alpha in your original drawing. Also I had sin and cos switched in my original edit.  Please note I corrected that.

Comment: thanks, yeah I just wonder if I calculated alpha in the right way. Because it doesn't work for me. (I use it for programming)

Comment: It should be $atan(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1})$ since $tan=\frac{sin}{cos}$.  I'm not familiar with the function atan2(a,b)

Comment: sadly doesn't work for me, but maybe there is another mistake. I will check it tmrw. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool.  One alternate method if you want to look at it is to find the distance between the two points.  Then find the ratio of $\frac{radius(n2)}{distance}$  and multiply that ratio times (x2-x1) and subtract that from x2.  And do the same with the y's.

Comment: ahh it works now, it was programming mistake on my side. Thanks =)

Comment: @turkeyhundt maybe you can help me with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548841/calculate-point-coordinates